# WPF EF Databinding: ItemsControl inside ListBox (master detail)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I am trying to place an ItemsControl inside a ListBox, but I have problems with the databinding for the inner ItemsControl.

EF Model:

[EF Database Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2hae.png)

EmployeeViewModel:

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public ListCollectionView Employees { get; set; }

```
public EmployeeViewModel()
{
    LoadData();
}

private void LoadData()
{
    using (testdbEntities context = new testdbEntities())
    {
        IEnumerable<Employees> query = (from e in context.Employees
                                        orderby e.Lastname
                                        select e);

        ObservableCollection<Employees> emp = new ObservableCollection<Employees>(query);
        Employees = new ListCollectionView(emp);
    }
}
```

}

View:

```
<Window x:Class="Employee.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Employee"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Employee.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:EmployeeViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listEmployees"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>,
                            <Run Text="{Binding Firstname}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <ItemsControl Name="empSkills" ItemsSource="{Binding Skills}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Skill}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ListBox binds perfectly, but the inner ItemsControl not.

What could be the problem?
Any help appreciated.

Output:
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Skills' value (type 'ICollection`1') from '' (type 'Employees_463D630561C8612AEA43DCC3EC6E2ACDC644CFB28D50978184F80EEEE86D779E'). BindingExpression:Path=Skills; DataItem='Employees_463D630561C8612AEA43DCC3EC6E2ACDC644CFB28D50978184F80EEEE86D779E' (HashCode=29719745); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Der Eigenschaftenaccessor Skills für das System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Employees_463D630561C8612AEA43DCC3EC6E2ACDC644CFB28D50978184F80EEEE86D779E-Objekt hat folgende Ausnahme verursacht: Die ObjectContext-Instanz wurde verworfen und kann nicht mehr für Vorgänge verwendet werden, für die eine Verbindung erforderlich ist. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Die ObjectContext-Instanz wurde verworfen und kann nicht mehr für Vorgänge verwendet werden, für die eine Verbindung erforderlich ist.

Comment: Let's see information from your Output Window. That should be screaming if there are binding errors. Please [Edit] your question and include that.

Answer (score 0):

Surely properties of Firstname and Lastname are in inner view model and not the main view model of Employees? Don't you have to change the datacontext to inner/ detail view model ?

Comment: ItemsControl inherently sets a new DataContext for child items.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the output led me to the solution. Thanks Lynn for the hint.

The problem is the usage of the using block in LoadData(). Employee data can be loaded, but prevents the lazy loading of skill data in the inner ItemsControl.

New working version of my EmployeeViewModel

```
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        private testdbEntities context = new testdbEntities();

        public ListCollectionView Employees { get; set; }

        public EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            LoadData();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            IEnumerable<Employees> query = (from e in context.Employees
                                            orderby e.Lastname
                                            select e);

            ObservableCollection<Employees> emp = new ObservableCollection<Employees>(query);
            Employees = new ListCollectionView(emp);
        }

    }
}
```